# POI Excel HSSFPicture Image and ALT TEXT

Tags: excel, apache-poi, alt, poi-hssf

I am using POI Excel HSSFPicture to create an image and add it to my excel file. I would like to add ALT TEXT to my image but I cannot find a way to add description to my image. Is there a way to add ALT TEXT to an image using POI for Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to display alt text when the Image is not visible, right? So just an alternate try to use the [Cell Comments](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellComments) to display the alt text.

Comment: The Excel file I generate with POI should be 508 compliance and the image should have a ALT TEXT  so that the screen reader can read it.